# if else statement stops at first IF

Tags: c#

I've got some problems with my code.. C#
if i run it it stops at the first If statement...

tried and looked for some more answers but diden't find anything that works

```
       private void Bereken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Afmetingen van het het blok
        var PL = int.Parse(EigenML.Text);
        var PB = int.Parse(EigenMB.Text);
        var PH = int.Parse(EigenMH.Text);

        // Afmetingen van het stuk
        var L = int.Parse(StukML.Text);
        var B = int.Parse(StukMB.Text);
        var H = int.Parse(StukMH.Text);
        LabelEigenML.Text = PL.ToString();
        LabelEigenMB.Text = PB.ToString();
        LabelEigenMH.Text = PH.ToString();

        var L1 = PL / L;
        var B1 = PB / B;
        var H1 = PH / H;
        var T1 = L1 * B1 * H1;

        var L2 = PL / L;
        var B2 = PB / B;
        var H2 = PH / H;
        var T2 = L2 * B2 * H2;

        var L3 = PL / L;
        var B3 = PB / B;
        var H3 = PH / H;
        var T3 = L3 * B3 * H3;

        var L4 = PL / L;
        var B4 = PB / B;
        var H4 = PH / H;
        var T4 = L4 * B4 * H4;

        var L5 = PL / L;
        var B5 = PB / B;
        var H5 = PH / H;
        var T5 = L5 * B5 * H5;

        var L6 = PL / L;
        var B6 = PB / B;
        var H6 = PH / H;
        var T6 = L6 * B6 * H6;

        if (T1 >= T2 && T1 >= T3 && T1 >= T4 && T1 >= T5 && T1 >= T6) {
            LabelStukML.Text = "Lengte" + L.ToString();
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Breedte" + B.ToString();
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Hoogte" + H.ToString();
            labelTotaal.Text = T1.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Should be 1");
        } else if (T2 >= T1 && T2 >= T3 && T2 >= T4 && T2 >= T5 && T2 >= T6)
        {
            LabelStukML.Text = "Lengte" + L.ToString();
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Hoogte" + H.ToString();
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Breedte" + B.ToString();
            labelTotaal.Text = T2.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Should be 2");

        } else if (T3 >= T1 && T3 >= T2 && T3 >= T4 && T3 >= T5 && T3 >= T6)
        {
            LabelStukML.Text = "Breedte" + B.ToString();
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Lengte" + L.ToString();
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Hoogte" + H.ToString();
            labelTotaal.Text = T3.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("Should be 3");


        }
        else if (T4 >= T1 && T4 >= T2 && T4 >= T3 && T4 >= T5 && T4 >= T6)
        {
            LabelStukML.Text = "Breedte" + B.ToString();
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Hoogte" + H.ToString();
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Lengte" + L.ToString();
            labelTotaal.Text = T4.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Should be 4");


        }
        else if (T5 >= T1 && T5 >= T2 && T5 >= T3 && T5 >= T4 && T5 >= T6)
        {
            LabelStukML.Text = "Hoogte" + H.ToString();
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Breedte" + B.ToString();
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Lengte" + L.ToString();
            labelTotaal.Text = T5.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Should be 5");


        }
        else if (T6 >= T1 && T6 >= T2 && T6 >= T3 && T6 >= T4 && T6 >= T5)
        {

            LabelStukML.Text = "Hoogte" + H.ToString();
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Lengte" + L.ToString();
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Breedte" + B.ToString();
            labelTotaal.Text = T6.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Should be 6");

        }
        else
        {

            LabelStukML.Text = "Error";
            LabelStukMB.Text = "Error" ;
            LabelStukMH.Text = "Error";
            labelTotaal.Text = "Error";
            Console.WriteLine("Should be 6");

        }







    }
}
```

}

It Should calculates sometings, then it looks to what is the biggest and print those things in a specific order, But i always get the Output of my first IF statement

Comment: Step through it, you'll see what the values of your locals are. If the first block in the if is executed, it will be because the first expression evaluates to true.

Comment: I am probably wrong, but at first look it seems that T1, T2... T6 will always be equals (L[n], B[n], H[n] are calculated with the same values and same algorithm)

Comment: @MatteoUmili Looks an awful lot like that to me. All the parts of the multiplication are calculated the same way for each `TX`.

Comment: @MatteoUmili I get the same feeling - they all carry out the same operations on the same set of values, so should all get the same result. And since all numbers are the same, the first If statement will evaluate to be true since it checks if the values are greater than **or equal to** each value of `Tx`

Comment: Maybe the iffer in your computer is busted. Once in a while these things happen because the condition is always true, but new programmers are a lot more reliable than microprocessors, so take a look at the iffer fluid. If it's cloudy you need to flush it and replace it, then bleed the registers. If it's clear, you may need your XOR plates resurfaced, or it could be the null calipers.

Comment: Omg.. stupid of me to not change that... and stupid that i never sa that problem..

Thanks for the reactions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

- All 6 calculation blocks contain the exact same formulas (as others have also pointed out).
- You are doing integer math, meaning the results are also integers, and they may all be rounded to 0 for certain inputs, e.g. if PL < L. Fix: use `Double.Parse(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull post,
Stupid of me to not see that issue,
Just copied and pasted the first and changed the numbers but not that PL/L, PB/B, PH/H where all the same :)

Works as a charm now :